# Why am I unable to locate and install OpenEduCat Timetable in Apps?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have managed to install OpenEduCat Core in my local 9.0c Odoo platform.  However, now I am still looking for ways on how to install OpenEduCat Timetable in the platform.

I tried to hit "Update Apps List" then search "Timetable" in the search bar in "Apps" however it gives me no result. What am I missing here?

Searching for "OpenEduCat" gives me only this

[image]

My Access Rights

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track the following:

- find the path of addons module
- is your module is at same place or path?
- give read/write/execute permission for that module
- restart your server
- Go to browser, from GUI, `Setting => Modules => Update Modules List =>` and Click on Update button
- Now go to `Setting => Modules => Local Modules =>` remove Apps filter on right hand side and type your module name

I hope after do these you will find your module.

**EDIT**

Active debugging mode. Open logged User form view and checked related access right.

Comment: There's no such thing as module on my installation. I doubt if there were any permission issue on the addon / module folder, I wouldn't be able to install `OpenEduCat Core` at the first place

Comment: Now you can see module. Active debugging mode. Open logged User form view and checked related access right.